# Missing first character from C string

Tags: rust, ffi

I am writing a binding to the `girara` library and I have an issue with the statusbar item text: the first character is missing.

Here is a part of my binding:

```
#[link(name="girara-gtk3")]
extern "C" {
    // Statusbar.
    pub fn girara_statusbar_item_add(session: *mut girara_session_t,
                                     expand: bool,
                                     fill: bool,
                                     left: bool,
                                     callback: girara_statusbar_event_t)
                                     -> *mut girara_statusbar_item_t;
    pub fn girara_statusbar_item_set_text(session: *mut girara_session_t,
                                          item: *mut girara_statusbar_item_t,
                                          text: *const c_char);
}
```

and here is how I call these functions:

```
let item = unsafe { girara_statusbar_item_add(session, true, true, true, None) };
assert!(item != 0 as *mut _);

let text = CString::new("girara-left").unwrap().as_ptr();
unsafe { girara_statusbar_item_set_text(session, item, text) };
```

But instead of showing `girara-left`, I only see `irara-left`.

Is using `CString` a good way to send `*const c_char` to a FFI?

Why is the first character missing?

**Update**

There is something weird hapening here.

If I change the code to:

```
let text = CString::new("girara-left").unwrap().as_ptr();
let text2 = CString::new("hello World").unwrap();
unsafe { girara_statusbar_item_set_text(session, item, text) };
```

(where `text2` is unused), the text `hello World` is shown, which does not make sense. It seems the pointer does not point at the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue came by the fact that the `CString` was dropped before the pointer was sent to the ffi function (see [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/scope-of-const-c-char-e-g-cstring-as-ptr/5469)).

The solution is to bind the `CString` to a variable:

```
let text = CString::new("girara-left").unwrap();
unsafe { girara_statusbar_item_set_text(session, item, text.as_ptr()) };
```

Comment: And make sure that your `girara_statusbar_item_set_text ` function doesn't keep a reference to that string beyond how long the `CString` lives...!

Comment: Note that Clippy has [a lint for that](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#temporary_cstring_as_ptr) (disclaimer: I’m a Clippy contributor).